# Why does this error occur when running my rails app in production, but not in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the command I'm using, as well as the error output:

```
ubuntu@lab:/var/www/vue-chat-app.lizardgizzards.com/vue-chat-app/backend-rails (master) $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3010
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        84: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        83: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        82: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        81: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        80: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        79: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        78: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        77: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        76: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        75: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        74: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        73: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        72: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        71: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        70: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        69: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        68: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        67: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        66: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
        65: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
        64: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
        63: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
        62: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
        61: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        60: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        59: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        58: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        57: from config.ru:in `<main>'
        56: from config.ru:in `new'
        55: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        54: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        53: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        52: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
        51: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        50: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        49: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        48: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        47: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        46: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        45: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        44: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        43: from /var/www/vue-chat-app.lizardgizzards.com/vue-chat-app/backend-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        42: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        41: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        40: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        39: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        38: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        37: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        36: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        35: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        34: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        33: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        32: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        31: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        30: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        29: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        28: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        27: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
        26: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
        25: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
        24: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
        23: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
        22: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
        21: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        20: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
        19: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:85:in `depend_on'
        18: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
        17: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
        16: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
        15: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
        14: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
        13: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
        12: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
        11: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
        10: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
         9: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
         8: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
         7: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
         6: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
         5: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
         4: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
         3: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         2: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         1: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': /var/www/vue-chat-app.lizardgizzards.com/vue-chat-app/backend-rails/app/controllers/chat_room_controller.rb:85: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end (SyntaxError)
```

This is the file it's apparently choking on, but I don't understand what the problem with it is:

```
class ChatRoomController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_chat_room, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def join
    user = User.find_by client_token: params[:client_token]

    if user
      user.join_room params[:room_name]
    else

    render :nothing => true
  end

  # GET /chat_rooms
  # GET /chat_rooms.json
  def index
    @chat_rooms = ChatRoom.all
  end

  # GET /chat_rooms/1
  # GET /chat_rooms/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /chat_rooms/new
  def new
    @chat_room = ChatRoom.new
  end

  # GET /chat_rooms/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /chat_rooms
  # POST /chat_rooms.json
  def create
    @chat_room = ChatRoom.new(chat_room_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @chat_room.save
        format.html { redirect_to @chat_room, notice: 'Chat room was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @chat_room }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @chat_room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /chat_rooms/1
  # PATCH/PUT /chat_rooms/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @chat_room.update(chat_room_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @chat_room, notice: 'Chat room was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @chat_room }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @chat_room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /chat_rooms/1
  # DELETE /chat_rooms/1.json
  def destroy
    @chat_room.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to chat_rooms_url, notice: 'Chat room was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_chat_room
      @chat_room = ChatRoom.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def chat_room_params
      params.fetch(:chat_room, {})
    end
end
```

I'm pretty sure I haven't even altered the above controller at all after generating it via scaffold generator.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing an end in the join-action.

It should be:

```
  def join
    user = User.find_by client_token: params[:client_token]

    if user
      user.join_room params[:room_name]
    else
      # .. Nothing here
    end # <--- missing end

    render :nothing => true
  end
```

The reason it errors in production-only is probably that the production environment has eager_load = true, while development will load files as it needs them. You can confirm this in config/environment/production.rb and development.rb files.